# Using a JSON script in HTML and show data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Here is the Link to JSON.
http://api.wunderground.com/api/c3d8a6a640832fd0/conditions/forecast/alert/q/29.9205347,73.8706849.json

This JSON file give data about weather

And I want to show this data, given by the above link into my HTML file. I am using JSON for the first time. So I need help linking this JSON file into my HTML document.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<span id="temp"></span>
<span id="high"></span>
<span id="low"></span>
<span id="windspeed"></span>
<span id="description"></span>
<span id="city"></span>
<span id="iconorimage"></span>
<span id="time"></span>
<span id="any thing else"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am ok, If I can show only temperature, city, weather icon [rain,sunny], a text description about weather, high/low, wind speed and time.

Comment: see i just dont know a single thing about how to grab this data from html, once i became able to access this data from my html file, rest i will do myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access json object similar to the way one access the object property in javascript.

```js
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url:"//api.wunderground.com/api/c3d8a6a640832fd0/conditions/forecast/alert/q/29.9205347,73.8706849.json",
  success: function(data){
    $('#city').text("City : " + data["current_observation"]["display_location"]["city"]);
    $('#high').text("High : " + "");//Insert data for high here
    $('#low').text("Low : " +""); //Insert data for low here
    $('#temp').text("Tempearature : " + data["current_observation"]["temperature_string"]);
    $('#description').text("Description : " + data["current_observation"]["icon"]);
    $('<img />').attr('src',data["current_observation"]["icon_url"]).appendTo($("#iconorimage"));
  $('#windspeed').text('WindSpeed : ' + data["current_observation"]["wind_kph"]);
  $('#time').text('Time : ' + data["current_observation"]["observation_time"]);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<span id="temp"></span><br/>
<span id="high"></span><br/>
<span id="low"></span><br/>
<span id="windspeed"></span><br/>
<span id="description"></span><br/>
<span id="city"></span><br/>
<span id="iconorimage"></span><br/>
<span id="time"></span><br/>
<span id="any thing else"></span><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ajax` for load data.

See example,

```
function getJson(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/c3d8a6a640832fd0/conditions/forecast/alert/q/29.9205347,73.8706849.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
getJson();
```

> It will return JSON decoded data.

Comment: can you plz show me an example what it will return and how to put that reurned data in javascript variable.

Comment: Check your console.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It may help you

jsFiddle for the same
https://jsfiddle.net/sd0zc43j/3/

Using below ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url:"//api.wunderground.com/api/c3d8a6a640832fd0/conditions/forecast/alert/q/29.9205347,73.8706849.json",
  success: function(data){       
   $('#city').html("City : " + data["current_observation"]["display_location"]["city"]);
   $('#high').html("High Fahrenheit: " + data["forecast"]["simpleforecast"]["forecastday"][0]["high"]["fahrenheit"] + " & Celsius: " + data["forecast"]["simpleforecast"]["forecastday"][0]["high"]["celsius"]);
   $('#low').html("Low Fahrenheit: " + data["forecast"]["simpleforecast"]["forecastday"][0]["low"]["fahrenheit"] + " & Celsius: " + data["forecast"]["simpleforecast"]["forecastday"][0]["low"]["celsius"]);
   $('#temp').html("Tempearature : " + data["current_observation"]["temperature_string"]);
   $('#windspeed').html("Wind Speed : " + data["current_observation"]["wind_string"]);
   $('#description').html("Description : " + data["current_observation"]["icon"]);
   // $('#iconorimage').html("Icon URL : " + data["current_observation"]["icon_url"]);
   $('#img').attr("src",data["current_observation"]["icon_url"]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Comment: Please Marked as answer for future references

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be  patronizing but I think the word you're looking for is parse.

Start by parsing something simpler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

It will help boost your confidence and you'll be glad you took the scenic route as opposed to jumping head first.

Answer (score 0):

you can send ajax request to this url

```
    $.ajax({url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/c3d8a6a640832fd0/conditions/forecast/alert/q/29.9205347,73.8706849.json", success: function(result){
            var data=JSON.Parse(result);
//and then you can access each of the property of json object for example
            data.current_observation.observation_location.city;

//but yes you might need to loop through to access like periods in forecast 
        }});
```

let me know if i am directing you in the correct direction?
That is what you want? please let me know if you need further clarification.
Thanks

Comment: you can use json object 'data' which we have parsed from received result to access needed properties. if get any difficulty in getting forecast property data  let me know.